# Find the values of a function in a region knowing its average value over any chord of the region

Tags: geometry, integral-transforms

Given a region $S$ in plane geometry, for any chord we can compute the average value of a function $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R}$ over the chord. Function $f$ and its derivatives are continuous in region S (function f is a physical quantity, actually).

[image]

If we indicate with $\overline{f}_{C_1C_2}$ the mean value of $f$ over the chord $\overline{C_1C_2}$, we have
$$\int_{\overline{C_1C_2}}f(x,y)=dist(C_1,C_2) \;\overline{f}_{C_1C_2}$$
The same for chord $\overline{C_3C_4}$, and so on.

Is it possible to find the value of $f$ for any point in the region $S$?

In the actual physical problem region $S$ is not always convex and may have holes, but if you think convexity makes the problem more affordable in a substantial way, you can assume it.

**Follow up**

I guess the inverse [Radon Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform) is what we need here.

Comment: I think you should restrict your investigation to the cases where $S$ is a convex region. Otherwise discontinuous chords should be tricky to work with.

Comment: @JeanMarie I think that the tricky point is other than the lack of convexity, but if you think convexity makes the difference you can assume it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $S$ includes the boundary curve, then you can find $f$ on the boundary since you just take small chords converging to the boundary point. 
If $f$ is a physical quantity, then one would expect it to be basically infinitely differentiable... at least as a toy model of the problem.

Ignoring that, if $S$ is convex, then the question is answered. At stated in this paper: [The X-Ray Transform](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X76900081). The X-ray transform of a function $f$ is gotten by collecting from $f$ only two pieces of data: for any point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and any direction $\theta$, the integral of $f$ along the line starting at $x$ and having the direction $\theta$ (and going in the opposite direction as well to make an entire line). The paper cites a result that $f$ is completely determined by its X-ray transform if $f$ is differentiable and having compact support (i.e. $f \neq 0$ on a bounded collection of regions) and there is an inversion formula that gives you $f$ from the transform if $f$ is also infinitely differentiable.

The X-ray transform asks for the integral along a line and I do not see any straight-forward way to address this besides the region being convex. If you were doing this computationally, then maybe you could manually feed in the integral along a line as the sum of the integrals along the chords that make up where $S$ coincides with that line.

The X-ray transform is related to taking X-rays (duh duh dum), in that when taking X-rays we can only pass X-rays into a concealed region trying to find out the density of it.

Comment: I would also add that taking the integral along a chord is very different than giving the average value on the chord without also giving the length of the chord. I would also note that that would add complications to my answer that I am unprepared to address.

Comment: The paper you cite is too technical for me, but I guess I grasped that the results are valid as long as $k<n/2$, where  $n$ is the dimension of the domain of $f$ and $k$ is the dimension of the subspace along which you can find the value of integral. For the real x-rays problem $n=3$ and $k=1$ so the condition is met, but in this case the condition is not met since $n=2$ and $k=1$.

Comment: I was referring to the bottom of page 62 just below the integral. It seems that those remarks apply to this case. Where in the paper did you find the $k < n/2$ result. I did not read the paper, but just found it as a reference. 
If the proof in the paper does not work out, then there are exercises and problems in Stein and Shakarchi's *Fourier Analysis*, Chapter 6 proving the relevant results if the function is a Schwartz function. (an example would be infinitely differentiable and compactly supported) So, I suppose that this is know enough to become a homework problem.

Comment: I added a 'follow up' to the question; reading about x-ray transform (cited also in page 62) I got to inverse Radon transform which seems the solution to this problem.

Comment: Yeah, that is what Stein and Shakarchi deal with. They just say that it coincides with the X-ray transform for $n = 2$. I just thought that the word "X-ray", might sound more appealing for one getting an idea about what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

If you change $f$ on a single point, it does not modify the mean values, so the answer is no.

It might be different given assumptions on $f$.

Comment: Function $f$ and its derivates are continuous in region S.

Comment: You should delete your answer.